# Matching the finite closure pattern ({x,y}) of regular expressions

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to write a grammar that will match the finite closure pattern for regular expressions ( i.e foo{1,3} matches 1 to 3 'o' appearances after the 'fo' prefix )

To identify the string {x,y} as finite closure it must not include spaces for example { 1, 3} is recognized as a sequence of seven characters.

I have written the following lexer and parser file but i am not sure if this is the best solution. I am using a lexical mode for the closure pattern which is activated when a regular expression matches a valid closure expression.

```
lexer grammar closure_lexer;

@header {   using System;
           using System.IO; }

@lexer::members{
              public static bool guard = true;
              public static int LBindex = 0;
}

OTHER : .;
NL : '\r'? '\n' ;
CLOSURE_FLAG :  {guard}?  {LBindex =InputStream.Index; }
                     '{' INTEGER ( ',' INTEGER? )? '}'
    { closure_lexer.guard     = false;
        // Go back to the opening brace
        InputStream.Seek(LBindex);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Closure Mode");
        Mode(CLOSURE);
        } -> skip

 ;

 mode CLOSURE;
 LB : '{';
 RB : '}' { closure_lexer.guard = true; 
            Mode(0); Console.WriteLine("Enter       Default Mode"); };
 COMMA : ',' ;
 NUMBER : INTEGER ;


 fragment INTEGER : [1-9][0-9]*;
```

and the parser grammar

```
 parser grammar closure_parser;

 @header {  using System;
        using System.IO; }

 options { tokenVocab = closure_lexer; }

 compileUnit
:     ( other {Console.WriteLine("OTHER: {0}",$other.text);} |
     closure {Console.WriteLine("CLOSURE: {0}",$closure.text);} )+
;

 other : ( OTHER | NL )+;

 closure : LB NUMBER (COMMA NUMBER?)? RB;
```

Is there a better way to handle this situation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks quite complex for such a simple task. You can easily let your lexer match one construct (preferably that without whitespaces, if you usually skip them) and the parser matches the other form. You don't even need lexer modes for that.

Define your closure rule:

```
CLOSURE
    : OPEN_CURLY INTEGER (COMMA INTEGER?)? CLOSE_CURLY
;
```

This rule will not match any form that contains e.g. whitespaces. So, if your lexer does not match CLOSURE you will get all the individual tokens like the curly braces and integers ending up in your parser for matching (where you then can treat them as something different).

**NB:** doesn't the closure definition also allow `{,n}` (same as `{n}`)? That requires an additional alt in the CLOSURE rule.

And finally a hint: your OTHER rule will probably give you trouble as it matches any char and is even located before other rules. If you have a whildcard rule then it should be the last in your grammar, matching everything not matched by any other rule.